# How can I watch to see when the number of items in an array changes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I created this code:

```
    $scope.$watch('grid.view.length', function () {
        if ($scope.grid.view != null) {
            var a = $scope.grid.view.length;
            var pane = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
            pane.data('jsp').reinitialise();
        }
    })
```

`grid.view` is an array.  All I need to do is see if the number of elements change but this seems not to trigger the watch when the number of elements inside of it changes. Am I doing this wrong ?

Maxim's comment sounds like a solution but I am not sure now. Would it better to just set up a $scope variable that holds the length and watch that. I am concerned if it does a lot of deep compares then this might be a performance problem. Note the grid.view is quite big.

Answer (score 1):

Use flag `true` to make deep watch:

Try:

```
$scope.$watch('grid.view.length', function () {
        if ($scope.grid.view != null) {
            var a = $scope.grid.view.length;
            var pane = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
            pane.data('jsp').reinitialise();
        }
    }, true)
```

Comment: If I use "true" then do I still need the .length? Also would it be better to set up as $scope variable something like $scope.abc = grid.view.length; and then watch that ?

Comment: I would use `grid.view.length`. Because you want to fire only on length change but not on content. It prevent you from additional watch loop (and sure , performance)

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is reasonable. From the docs:

*To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. It also means that watching complex options will have adverse memory and performance implications.*

Using another scope variable that just holds the length is an overkill in your case.

`$watch` also accepts a function as a parameter. A change in the return value triggers a call to the listener:

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope){
    return grid.view.length;
},function(newValue, oldValue){
    /* do something */
    console.log("yeah! "+newValue);
});
```